# Windows delete with wildcards deleting erratically

Tags: windows, cmd, wildcard, delete-file

This is driving me crazy.  Basically, I have a program that outputs tables to a flat file for multiple databases with the same structure.  These files get named in the format `tablename_####.dat`, where `####` is the 4 digit company number.  After these are all created, the program then combines all of the files by tablename, and adds a timestamp on the end.  So, the final file name is in the format `tablename_YYYYMMDD_HHmmSS.dat`.  Finally, I want to delete all of the individual .dat files, leaving only the combined, time stamped files.

This works just fine for all of the tables, except for the table VEX.  For example, I have files:

```
VEX_1234.dat
VEX_5678.dat
VEX_0987.dat
```

which combine to form `VEX_20150414_144352.dat`.  After this, I run the command:

```
`del *_????.dat`
```

This deletes all of the tables' individual files (`V_1234.dat`, `PAT_9534.dat`, etc.), while leaving the combined files (`V_20150414_142311.dat`, `PAT_20150413_132113.dat`) ...except for VEX.  It deletes both the individual files and the combined file.  Shouldn't this only delete files that end with an underscore, 4 characters, and ".dat"?

I know this has to be something really simple that I'm missing.  What is going on?

Comment: If you use `dir *_????.dat`, does the combined file show up?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Very strange.  There are around 30 other files in that folder that end in ######_######.dat, but the VEX one is the only one getting picked up.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your issue is caused by short 8.3 file names.

The `?` wildcard can match 0 or 1 character if it precedes a dot. Your file mask of `*_????.dat` will match any name that has any number of characters, followed by a `_`, followed by 0 to 4 characters, followed by the `.dat` extension. The tricky thing is it will attempt to match both the long file name, ***and any short 8.3 name***, if it exists.

Try issuing `dir /x *.dat`, and look at the short name of the problem file. I suspect it will match your file mask.

There are patterns with how short names are derived, but there is no way to predict the short name of any given file unless you are aware of all existing short names within the folder, and then you would be relying on undocumented behavior.

This is a fairly common problem. If your files are on an NTFS drive and you have admin rights, then you can disable short file name generation. But this does not remove already existing short names.

The best general solution is to pipe DIR /B through FINDSTR to remove the unwanted files, and process the result with FOR /F to delete each file individually. The FINDSTR below will exclude file names that contain two or more `_` characters.

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b *.dat^|findstr /v "_.*_"') do del "%%F"
```